# Html compression by means php of code, does this code cause any load and is there any benefit from it?

Tags: php, datalife-engine

I found the html minification code on the Internet. I would like to ask the knowledgeable, is there any sense from such a code? I am also interested in the possible load from using this code. I would also like to know which of the three options is better ?

In index.php which is at the root of the site above the line

```
@ob_start ();
```

insert code (option 1)

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {
$search = array('/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s', '/<!--(.*?)-->/', '/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s');
$replace = array('>', '<', '\\1', '', '>', '<', '\\1');
$buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
return $buffer;
}
```

OR option 2

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {
$search = array('/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s', '/<!--(.*?)-->/', '/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s');
$replace = array('>', '<', '\\1', '<!--\\1-->', '>', '<', '\\1');
$buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
return $buffer;
}
```

OR option 3

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {
$search = array(

'/\>[^\S ]+/s',
'/[^\S ]+\</s',
'/\s{5,}/'

);

$replace = array(
'>',
'<',
'\\1'
);
$buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
return $buffer;
}
```

Next in /engine/modules/main.php find

```
echo $tpl->result['main'];
```

replace with

```
ob_start("sanitize_output");
echo $tpl->result['main'];
ob_end_flush();
```

[Source](https://byroot.ru/99-minifikaciya-html-koda-stranicy-v-dle.html)

Comment: No need to write your own code for compression. You should be able to use the php's inbuilt compression which will be more efficient.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression

Also please check the Webserver doc for  enabling compression in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to code compression methods by yourself, use the inbuilt compression instead. Here are some you may want:

- Gzip string compression: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php
- Output buffering with gzip handler: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php

Furthermore, in your provided codes:

- Option 1 is basically deleting line breaks and comments in your code.
- Option 2 deletes line breaks only.
- Option 3 deletes line breaks only.

*Option 1 deletes most things so it will be mostly minimized.*

For options 1 and 2 I don't see any point in adding `'/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s'`, they are just doubling things.

**It's not necessary to minimize html code, it reduces its readability (or maybe that's your purpose) and does not actually decrease the loading speed on small files (you need some MBs to see significant results) but may even increase it because it needs to perform regex checks.**

See this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) for more info.

Comment: Full answer. Thanks a ton!